# How to access subproject gradle file ext properties from root project gradle file

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a subproject Gradle like

```
project.ext.foo = "bar"
...
```

And I have the root project Gradle file as

```
subprojects {
    if (project.hasProperty("foo")) {
        // not true
    }

    def hasFoo = project.findProperty('foo') ?: ""
    // not finding it

}
```

I need to configure the subprojects in the root gradle file based on a project set or not set in the individual subproject.

I tried to dump with `project.properties.each {}` but cannot spot the property I am setting.

Answer (score 1):

In multiproject builds, Gradle will first evaluate and configure the root project, and then configure sub-projects.

So in your root project `subprojects` closure you try to access sub-project properties which has not yet been set, since sub-project has not been configured yet.

Adding some debug logs can help to understand the configuration lifecycle:

*root project build.gradle*

```
println("root: start configure phase for root project")

subprojects {
    println("root: configuring subproject $project.name")
    if (project.hasProperty("foo")) {
        println("root: property 'foo' found on subproject $project.name")
    } else {
        println("root: property 'foo' !! NOT !!  found on subproject $project.name")
    }
}

println("root: end configure phase for  root project")
```

*subproject build.gradle*

```
println("sub-1: start configure phase for subproject $project.name")

println("sub-1: setting foo property")
project.ext.foo = "bar"

println("sub-1: end configure phase for subproject $project.name")
```

Execution result:

```
> Configure project :
root: start configure phase for root project
root: configuring subproject sub1
root: property 'foo' !! NOT !!  found on subproject sub1
root: end configure phase for  root project

> Configure project :sub1
sub-1: start configure phase for subproject sub1
sub-1: setting foo property
sub-1: end configure phase for subproject sub1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 206ms
```

##### Solutions

A first simple solution would be to use the [`project.afterEvaluate { }`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#afterEvaluate-groovy.lang.Closure-) feature in your root project, to make sure subprojects have been configured before configuring things that depend on the `foo` property :

*root project build.gradle*

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { 
        println("root: configuring subproject $project.name")
        if (project.hasProperty("foo")) {
            println("root: property 'foo' found on subproject $project.name")
        } else {
            println("root: property 'foo' !! NOT !!  found on subproject $project.name")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
> Configure project :
root: start configure phase for root project
root: end configure phase for  root project

> Configure project :sub1
sub-1: start configure phase for subproject sub1
sub-1: setting foo property
sub-1: end configure phase for subproject sub1
root: configuring subproject sub1
root: property 'foo' found on subproject sub1   <<<=== OK !
```

A better solution to handle shared configuration between subprojects would be to use plugins: please have a look at this dedicated [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins_vs_cross_configuration)